# Overriding Core File in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, javascript

I am new magento and I want to override my "Data.php" file which is located at **/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Helper/Data.php**

I want to remove the unwanted states from DropDownList.

Below is my Function in Data.php file

```
protected function _getRegions($storeId)
    {
        $countryIds = array();

        $countryCollection = $this->getCountryCollection()->loadByStore($storeId);
        foreach ($countryCollection as $country) {
            $countryIds[] = $country->getCountryId();
        }

        /** @var $regionModel Mage_Directory_Model_Region */
        $regionModel = $this->_factory->getModel('directory/region');
        /** @var $collection Mage_Directory_Model_Resource_Region_Collection */
        $collection = $regionModel->getResourceCollection()
            ->addCountryFilter($countryIds)
            ->load();

        $regions = array(
            'config' => array(
                'show_all_regions' => $this->getShowNonRequiredState(),
                'regions_required' => $this->getCountriesWithStatesRequired()
            )
        );

        foreach ($collection as $region) {
            if (!$region->getRegionId()) {
                continue;
            }

            //EOF Custom Logic Here
            $regions[$region->getCountryId()][$region->getRegionId()] = array(
                'code' => $region->getCode(),
                'name' => $this->__($region->getName())
            );
        }
        return $regions;
    }
```

In the above function I want to add code for removing the unwanted states from dropdown. I have added the code for this but when I am adding in the above function I am not getting any effect.

```
protected function _getRegions($storeId)
    {
        $countryIds = array();

        $countryCollection = $this->getCountryCollection()->loadByStore($storeId);
        foreach ($countryCollection as $country) {
            $countryIds[] = $country->getCountryId();
        }

        /** @var $regionModel Mage_Directory_Model_Region */
        $regionModel = $this->_factory->getModel('directory/region');
        /** @var $collection Mage_Directory_Model_Resource_Region_Collection */
        $collection = $regionModel->getResourceCollection()
            ->addCountryFilter($countryIds)
            ->load();

        $regions = array(
            'config' => array(
                'show_all_regions' => $this->getShowNonRequiredState(),
                'regions_required' => $this->getCountriesWithStatesRequired()
            )
        );
        $excludeRegions = array('AE','AA');
        foreach ($collection as $region) {
            if (!$region->getRegionId()) {
                continue;
            }

             //BOF Custom Logic Here
            ***$regionCode = $region->getCode();
            $this->_select->from(array('region'=>$this->_regionTable),
            array('region_id'=>'region_id', 'country_id'=>'country_id', 'code'=>'code', 'default_name'=>'default_name')
            )->where('code NOT IN (?)', $exclude_regions);***

            //EOF Custom Logic Here
            $regions[$region->getCountryId()][$region->getRegionId()] = array(
                'code' => $region->getCode(),
                'name' => $this->__($region->getName())
            );
        }
        return $regions;
    }
```

Even the whole Data.php file along with the above change i kept in local directory but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't encourage you to use this way of override, like creating `app/code/local/Mage/Directory/Helper/Data.php`, this is just the good way for spaghetti code..

1. Create a module `Vids_Directory` in pool `local` like `app/code/local/Vids/Directory`
2. Create `app/etc/modules/Vids_Directory.xml` and this code :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Vids_Directory>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
               <depends>
                   <Mage_Directory />
               </depends>
           </Vids_Directory>
       </modules>
   </config>
   ```
3. Create `app/code/local/Vids/Directory/etc/config.xml` and add this code :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Vids_Directory>
               <version>0.1.0</version>
           </Vids_Directory>
       </modules>
       <global>
           <helpers>
               <directory>
                   <rewrite>
                       <data>Vids_Directory_Helper_Data</data>
                   </rewrite>
               <directory>
           </helpers>
       </global>
   </config>
   ```
4. Finally, you can create `app/code/local/Vids/Helper/Data.php` and add this :

   ```
   <?php

   class Vids_Directory_Helper_Data extends Mage_Directory_Helper_Data 
   {
       protected function _getRegions($storeId) {
           // Your code inside
       }
   }
   ```

**Note** : your code `$this->_select->from...` is referring to nothing, be careful (or probably you missed to add your complete code ?).

Hope it will help you :).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this but my page did not loaded at all .Only the website symbol is displayed.And can you tell me how should I edit this code "$this->_select->from..."?

Comment: If you to add more filter on region collection, you can use the function `addFieldToFilter()` and the condition `nin` in your case. For example :
`$collection->addFieldToFilter('region_code', array('nin', array('AE', 'AA')));`.
You can do this when Magento is creating the `$collection`object ;)

Comment: @see http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/addattributetofilter/ ;)